# ¿Cómo podría acceder al valor pasado por una ruta en VUE JS?

Tags: vue.js, router

Tengo la siguiente ruta en mi router.js:

```
{
    path: "/empleados/historial/:id",
    name: "historial_empleado",
    component: historial_empleado,
},
```

Necesito hacer una validación con ese ':id' cuando la ruta sea llamada por decirlo así, básicamente en el **beforeEach** del **router.js**. Pero no se cómo hacer para obtenerlo precisamente en mi beforeEach, ¿será posible hacerlo?¿cómo podría lograrlo?.

Answer (score 0):

Logré hallar la solución yo mismo, para quienes les surge o les llega a surgir la misma incógnita: Para obtener ese valor o parámetro pasado por la url cuando se carga, como indicaba en el ejemplo "/empleados/historial/:id/"; para obtener ese ":id", ya sea para hacer cualquier tipo de validación, se obtiene con la línea:

```
var parametro_id = to.params.id;
```

Aquí estoy guardandolo en una variable, la explicación lógica es, para cuando se envíe a otra ruta ya sea mediante un botón o por la url directamente, se ejecutará el método **beforeEach**, **to** indica la ruta hacia donde se está enviando o se está haciendo la petición de ir, params son los parámetros que se están enviando mediante esta ruta, yo le paso solo uno: **id**